# How can i query the version of the node using the API?

Tags: stellar-core

I want to know the version of a node using API that can be called externally over the network(rest, etc, excluding cli).
I know I can use the CLI to know the version, but can't I use the API?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Horizon returns all that data on the root (e.g. https://horizon.stellar.org/).

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).